# How to execute a function at WordPress back end on a particular day, week, date or month once automatically

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a counter plugin in WordPress, the counter have facility to increment to x number on a particular day, date, week or month to current date using php.

Comment: add some code, dude

Comment: Please edit your question after you have read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Wordpress cron is that you cannot set it to a specific date, you have to specify an inverval (in seconds). So if you want it to run for instance once every 12 months - you have to run it every 30.4375 days and that is 2629800 seconds.

You can read the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/) which is recommended, but for a quick solution you can use the [Schedule Cron Job Event Generator](https://generatewp.com/schedule_event/), which for an event run every month generates the following code:

```
// Scheduled Action Hook
function every_month_cron_hook( ) {
}

// Custom Cron Recurrences
function custom_cron_job_recurrence( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_month'] = array(
        'display' => __( 'every_month_label', 'textdomain' ),
        'interval' => 2629800,
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_cron_job_recurrence' );

// Schedule Cron Job Event
function custom_cron_job() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'every_month_cron_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_month', 'every_month_cron_hook' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'custom_cron_job' );
```

If you want is to start on a specific date - just change the line starting `wp_schedule_event(time()..` according to your liking - this argument specifies *The first time that you want the event to occur. This must be in a UNIX timestamp format.*

The best solution is to use [Unix cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) if available, which gives you maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to [Wordpress Cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) 
Here is a nice documentation from Wordpress. Give it a try and come back here if you encounter some troubles ;)
[Scheduling WP Cron Events](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/)

Basically you define your function and hook it to an action.
Then you use wp_schedule_event to schedule it. It can be confusing at first but it's not that hard. Hope it helps.